# pause/resume animation by mouse events jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

here is a code: http://jsfiddle.net/XqS2f/

i understand what i need to save somehow current positions of blocks or something like this... but may be exist another solution which is more easy to use?

```
$(function () {
var startTime = new Date();    
tl = $('#thumbs_list');
tl.css('overflow', 'hidden');

var slider = $('#thumbs_list_frame'),
    items = slider.find('li');
var sliderHeight = slider.height(),
    itemsNum = items.length,
    itemHeight = items.height();


slider.css('top', '-' + (sliderHeight + itemHeight) + 'px');

var startPos = slider.css('top');

items.first().before(items.clone());
items.last().after(items.clone());

scrollItems(slider,sliderHeight,itemHeight,startPos,4);
var endTime = +new Date();
var diff = endTime - startTime;

setInterval(function(){ 
    scrollItems(slider,sliderHeight,itemHeight,startPos,4);
}, 300);
```

});

function scrollItems(container, targetsHeight, increment, startPos, temps) {
    var secs = temps * 3000;

```
container.mouseover(function(){
  container.stop(true);
}).mouseout(function(){
  //container.animate();
});   

container.animate({
    'top': '-' + ((targetsHeight * 2) + increment) + 'px'
}, secs, 'linear', function () {
    container.css('top', startPos);      
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try add this code in document ready and this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbL6c/5/):

```
var itvl = setInterval(function(){ 
        scrollItems(slider,sliderHeight,itemHeight,startPos,4);
    }, 4000);

    $('#container').hover(function(){
        clearInterval(itvl);
        $('#slider').stop();
    },function () {
        var itvl = setInterval(function(){ 
            scrollItems(slider,sliderHeight,itemHeight,startPos,4);
        }, 4000);
});
```

Comment: thank you for quick answer but is not stop... and work very strange... when you try sometimes stay cursor over a while, and this is not resume when do mouse away form block.